# Is it possible to be sure a certain file can be written to without opening it?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, file-io

I wrote a custom control for output file name selection with the typical: text box for the filename, a "browse" button, and some other functionality specific to my application.

The text box changes color depending on the filename. If the file location cannot be written to, it turns red. If the file already exist, it turns yellow. Otherwise, it remains the system-assigned color.

To see if a file exists, I use IO.File.Exists; simple enough.

I implemented the "if the file can be written to" as a simple try-catch block where a file is actually opened, something written in it, closed, then deleted. If at any point an exception is thrown, I know the user can't use that filename and I turn the text box red.

This is a catch-all; since I'm doing the *actual* operation I intend to do, it is fool-proof. However, it seems irresponsible to have software creating and deleting files like crazy just to see if it can.

So my question is, how do I replicate this functionality without creating files? I can see I have to:

1. Check the path for legality (e.g., 'z:' is not a valid filename). This entails parsing the path and making sure all directories exist.
2. If the location exists, I have to check for write permissions. (Several answered questions exist to this end.)

Is there anything else?

EDIT

Within minutes I see people are already voting up an answer that criticizes that I'm checking *at all* that the file is accessible before actual writing to it occurs. While I appreciate experts "standing back" from my question to see whether or not there is a completely different way to achieve it, telling me I shouldn't be doing it is not an answer to my question.

So let me elaborate on my application (I am not expecting hundreds of users at the same time).

I use this file chooser control in data acquisition applications. In many situations the test that you are about to run is "expensive" in one way or another. Therefore it is critical to set things up very carefully. Overwriting data can be very expensive (and for the fearful user I have a checkbox that will append the date and time down to the millisecond to the filename).

So the purpose of my indicator colors is not to provide a surefire way for the software to know the file can be written to (that check is still done at the instant it actually has to), it's to serve as an indicator to the user that at least he has set up the file name correctly so if he goes forward he is guaranteed not to overwrite old data and he's *almost* sure a last-minute IO error (filename typo) won't let the experiment run unrecorded.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest this - don't check anything before user commits the action. With your current approach, even if you verified the file is okay, it may be locked 5 seconds later when the user actually commits to write to a file. Doing preliminary checks may only give user a false impression of estimated success. Especially consider this point on a terminal server with 100+ simultaneous users.

There is nothing wrong with showing a prompt with Retry/Cancel/etc. if no access, and let user decide.

**EDIT:**

No offense, but there are standards on how such collisions are handled. Windows standard is to show a prompt to the user. Also consider this - if you suddenly have a deny in write access to the folder, which you are not expected to have, you probably need to hire another system/network administrator.

If the operation is costly, make sure this guy is paid well. C'mon, what if your network goes down during writing? Hard drive? Router? There are many reasons why writing to a file can be interrupted, and you should be prepared for that. If you cannot afford it, make sure you have invested in good infrastructure and good people to support it.

Down on earth, you can increase chances of acquiring a successful lock on the file:

- Pick a unique file name, using datetime-based hash as a suffix/prefix.
- Write to user's home directory, also known as `%UserProfile%`, it is likely that you will succeed.

Comment: There's also the possibility of using a threaded approach for this and submitting data once the file has been unlocked.  The only problem, of course, is whether any changes to the file while locked have an affect the data about to be written.

Comment: @Westie: keeping data in RAM in case of file IO trouble is a good idea.

Comment: @Neolisk: thanks for your insights. But you are overcomplicating this whole thing, and still not answering my question. You are merely stating your opinion, be it standard or not (and I don't need to follow any standards in this application). It's OK that you post that, but what's sad is that people vote up an answer that says I *shouldn't* do what I want, over an answer that is actually trying to tell me *how* to do what I want.

Comment: @pelesl: The above answer is based on experience, totally unbiased. I could understand your reaction, if we were trying to sell you on something. At my present workplace we provide end-to-end solutions for insurance companies, I know how production runs and what "expensive" means. If everybody is telling you not to do what you want, it probably makes sense to reconsider your decision. Also note that you did not quite explain your need, as if you are trying to hide parts of your very secret know-how workflow. This is usually not how you seek for help.

Answer (score 1):

I can understand your problem with not wanting to risk losing "expensive" data because the file couldn't be written and a responsible program will do it's best to avoid the situation.

I would do this by cacheing the results.  Before the test is run write a mock result to a file somewhere in the user data space, then leave the file open and write the real result to the file.  After this is done write it to the user-specified file.  Provide a recovery option that will read the cache file and write it out to the user's file.

Your approach could fail because just because the file was writable at the start doesn't mean it's still writable.  The network could have gone down.  Someone could have removed the flash drive.  Someone else could be doing a large data transfer through a buggy router.  (Real world case--it took me a **long** time to prove it was a network problem and not my program.   finally accepted it was their fault when I showed that dir :*.* /s on multiple machines at once would almost certainly cause one or more to fail.)

Comment: Nice idea. Write to a location that I know works, then copy it to where the user wants it. A bit safer than storing in RAM as far crashes are concerned.